# Why does my server (which uses BufferedReader) not receive all the data sent by the client?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am creating a Swing Whiteboard App in which there's an input device and an output device. The person using the input device can paint onto the screen and that screen is then displayed on the output device (as well as on the input device).

The drawing/painting works well on the input device (which is the client), but I am unable to send the coordinates to the server (output device) properly.

The first problem is that the BufferedReader in the server doesn't receive the data immediately. Even though I'm drawing on the input device, the server draws the lines 30 seconds later.

The second problem is that the server doesn't receive all the coordinates even though they are being sent by the client, and thus the lines are incomplete/broken.

**EDIT:
I implemented a counter and what I noticed is that the server receives coordinate pairs only for half the lines that are drawn on the client side, thereby resulting in the incomplete image. Furthermore, it receives them in an alternate fashion. (ie. if the client sends coordinates for line1, line2, line3, line4, the server receives only line1 and line3 (this is why an incomplete image is displayed).**

This is the code I have in the mouseDragged ActionListener.

```
g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
sendData();
```

```
public void sendData() { 
        // I am using a PrintWriter as the 'out'
        out.println(oldX + " " + oldY + " " + currentX + " " + currentY);
    }
```

Here is the code in the server which receives the data

```
while (true) { 
    if (in.readLine() != null) { 
        String message = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(i + ": " + message);
        drawOnImage(message);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The full code in the file is below.

Client Side

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class DrawArea extends JComponent {

    // Image in which we're going to draw
    private Image image;
    // Graphics2D object ==> used to draw on
    private Graphics2D g2;
    // Mouse coordinates
    private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;



    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public DrawArea() throws IOException {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);


        socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777); // connecting to correct port.
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Connected");

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // save coord x,y when mouse is pressed
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });


        ArrayList<String> coords = new ArrayList();
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                // coord x,y when drag mouse
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();



                if (g2 != null) {
                    // draw line if g2 context not null
                    g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                    sendData();

                    coords.add(oldX + "," + oldY + " " + currentX + "," + currentY);
                    System.out.println(coords.size());
                    System.out.println(oldX + "," + oldY + " " + currentX + "," + currentY);

                    // refresh draw area to repaint
                    repaint();
                    // store current coords x,y as olds x,y
                    oldX = currentX;
                    oldY = currentY;
                }
            }
        });
    }



    public void sendData() { 
        out.println(oldX + " " + oldY + " " + currentX + " " + currentY);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            // image to draw null ==> we create
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            // enable antialiasing
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            // clear draw area
            clear();
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

       public void clear() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.white);
        // draw white on entire draw area to clear
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }
```

Server Side

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    static Socket socket;


    BufferedReader in; // reading. receiving data.



    TestDraw drawOutput; // this is the canvas on which the lines are drawn

    public Server(TestDraw drawOutput) {
        this.drawOutput = drawOutput;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Running");

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);

            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("A Client Connected");


            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));



            draw = false;


            int i = 1;
            while (true) { 
                if (in.readLine() != null) { 
                    String message = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(i + ": " + message);
                    drawOnImage(message);
                    i++;
                }
            }



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } 

    }


    void drawOnImage(String message) {

    String[] splitted = message.split(" ");
    int pointOneX = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
    int pointOneY = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
    int pointTwoX = Integer.parseInt(splitted[2]);
    int pointTwoY = Integer.parseInt(splitted[3]);


    drawOutput.g2.drawLine(pointOneX,pointOneY,pointTwoX,pointTwoY);

    drawOutput.repaint();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintWriter` and the network socket accumulate data in an internal buffer. The buffer needs to be "flushed" to make sure the data is sent as soon as possible.

One way to do this is set the "autoflush" property when constructing the PrintWriter. This will make sure the buffers get flushed on every call to `println`.

```
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Another way is to call flush yourself when you think it's needed, for example:

```
out.println(oldX + " " + oldY + " " + currentX + " " + currentY);
out.flush();
```

As for the problem on the receiving side, it's because of calling `readLine` twice. Each call reads a new line, and you are basically discarding the first line.

Change

```
if (in.readLine() != null) { 
    String message = in.readLine();
```

to

```
String message = in.readLine();
if (message != null) {
```

Comment: After doing what you mentioned above, the data is sent immediately; however, the painting on the server side is still not complete. What I mean is that not every line is drawn (the second issue I mentioned above). In my code, I implemented a counter and what I noticed is that the server receives coordinate pairs only for half the lines that are drawn on the client side, thereby resulting in the incomplete image.

Comment: oh I forgot that part of your question - see the update